# Magento 1.9.x Local.xml file what is the <model> tag for?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

Ive been trying to find an explanation for the Model tag in the local.xml file in magento:

for example a magento project im working with contains:

```
<model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
```

Im curious as to what magento is reading, is it behaving in a mysql4 manor? can I upgrade this?

Im not looking for DBA explanations on how magentos should be architected, im purely looking at this XML of model.

Comment: Could you post the full xml tree containing that tag please. Because by itself it doesn't make much sense. And also what's the local.xml file path?

Comment: Hi @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have managed to find out this by speaking to some Magento Devs. 

In answer to your question, I wont post the local xml file as it contains sensitive information. However if you want to view your own its, app/etc folder.

Comment: oh ok I thought you were referring to a theme local.xml and not the one in app/etc

Answer (score 1):

The within the local.xml file, the reference to mysql4 is not related to the version of DBos you are using, it relates to the resource model that is contained in the core of the system.